# Reference for the technique of completing number fields

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Most algebraic number theory texts I've come across treat global and local fields somewhat separately. In practice, I know the technique is often to start with a question about global fields, and then take the completion at each prime $\mathfrak{p}$, prove the statement there, and use a local-to-global theorem to get back the statement over the global field.

**I'm wondering if anyone has a good reference for the basics of what happens to number fields when you take the completion at a prime?** I'm thinking of results like: if $L / K$ is an extension of (global) number fields, and $p \in \mathcal{O}_K$ lying under $q \in \mathcal{O}_L$, then $L_q / K_p$ is an extension of local fields with ramification degree equal to $e(q / p)$ and the like.

Ideally, there would be a survey/chapter etc. on the basic results about what happens when you take completions to go from global to local.

**Edit**: Adding the closest reference I've found: [These notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2021fa/LectureNotes11.pdf) from Drew Sutherland's MIT course are a pretty good approximation of what I'm looking for - Section 11.4 gives the main results, but I'm still interested in other options.

Comment: Have you looked at Neukirch’s *Algebraic Number Theory*?

Comment: I have, but looking over the first couple of chapters, I didn't see what I was looking for. His section on completion seems to only cover how to take a completion, not results about splitting of primes etc. Apologies if I missed it in there though

Comment: Looks like maybe I should be looking in the section on extensions of valuations rather than on completions...

Comment: Maybe the results are more scattered, but I thought he had a few results looking like this…